# Why such a basic script is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here I am doing a basic trigger example but jquery is unable to execute it. I know jquery has some issues with such kind of trigger but isn't there any solution for the same.

Demo of code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/program_me/4eF2x/)

Comment: Why is it not working? Is it unemployed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/4eF2x/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a click object, just do this:

```
  $('#link').click();
```

This will only work though if the click() function has been already bound by jQuery, but may be what you're looking for.

Otherwise, if you're trying to open a new window using javascript, use `window.open('url','_blank','width=100,height=100');`

Instead of `window.location` like the others have posted, this will not open in a new target window.

There are also many more attributes you can set for the opening window in addition to `width` and `height` in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
// you have to assign a click event handler for anchor tag

$('#link').on('click', function() {
   window.location = this.href;
});

$('#btn').click(function(){

    $('#link').trigger('click'); // or $('#link').click();
    alert("I am alerting but link is not triggered");

});
```

#### Note

Click is not default behavior to anchor tag.So if you want something what you want to do, your have to assign click event handler to anchor previously and then trigger that event. And one important think is that before triggering any event by jquery, jquery should inform about that event.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4eF2x/7/)**

### To open in a new window do like following:

```
$('#link').on('click', function() {
  window.open(this.herf,this.target);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4eF2x/10/)**

Comment: this redirects to another url, but does not open in a new window as per the op's example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with jQuery or `trigger`.

For jQuery to trigger your link, **jQuery needs to know that you first assign a click handler to your link**:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    window.location = this.href;
});
​
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4eF2x/5/)**

Comment: this redirects to another url, but does not open in a new window as per the op's example.

Comment: @ZeeTee: The ***main*** issue is pointed out. As for new window, `window.open` can be put to use. `window.open(this.href)`

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that click() will not trigger the default behavior on a link, even if nothing else is preventing it. So you can't use click() by itself to simulate the user clicking on a link and being taken to another url.

This is why you need to attach an event handler to the `link` to handle the click-event

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    // navigate to page
});
```